# Typescript angular: Strip all spaces from textboxes but not enter key

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have the below that strip out all spaces but unfortunately that's also removed the enter key.

I just want spaces removed but not the enter key.

```
    static stripDoubleSpaces(str: string): string {
    if (!!str) {
        return str.replace(/\s+/g, ' ');
    } else {
        return str;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Enter key press is basically `\n` character and `\r` is carriage return.
You can use double negation to match all whitespaces except `\r` and `\n`. `\s` matches **all whitespaces**, `\S` matches **all non-whitespaces**.

If you want to strip all concurrent whitespaces to single-space:

```js
static stripSpaces(str: string): string {
    return (str || "").replace(/[^\S\r\n]+/g, " ")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this simply using:

```
str.replace(/[ \t\r]+/g,"");
```